# Stream in wcf project points incorrect assembly in MVC

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF project, i have class

```
class Item
{
 [DataMember]
 public Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

I add this service to my website as service reference, i uncheck `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`, because it shows various warning. The service referenced as "ProcessSVC". when i access the FileByteStream in Item object, i expect it is "System.IO.Stream" object, but it points to ProcessSVC.Stream.

Comment: what warnings did you get? Have you activated the streaming mode for your WCF service? (you can find a good tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I get warning "Custom Tool Warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType". I activate streaming support "<binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streamed"/>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is VS 2010, when i upgrade my project on VS 2013, it disappears. I think proxy code generation(Add service reference) may be the culprit.